# Escaping strings in Python subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, linux, awk

I try to invoke an awk script in my python script. I use subprocess.Popen():

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR<5{ print "SET", "\""$1"\"", "\""$2"|"$3"|"$4"\"" }' folder/file.tsv
```

This is the script:

```
import os
import subprocess

goal_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "folder", "file.tsv")

args = ["awk", '-F"\t"', 'NR<5{ print "SET", "\""$1"\"", "\""$2"|"$3"|"$4"\"" }', "{0}".format(goal_dir)]

process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
```

But it doesn't seem to properly escape the literals.

Comment: Did you mean `NF<5` instead of `NR<5`?

Comment: @HaiVu No, NR is record number.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
subprocess.Popen(r'''awk -F"\t" 'NR<5{ print "SET", "\""$1"\"","\""$2"|"$3"|"$4"\"" }' %s''' % goal_dir, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

OR

```
args = ["awk", '-F"\t"', r"""'NR<5{ print "SET", "\""$1"\"", "\""$2"|"$3"|"$4"\"" }'""", "{0}".format(goal_dir)]    
process = subprocess.Popen(" ".join(args), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```